# Module is not found after import and download

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I just switched my code from Replit to Visual Code Studio and I have pip, python, and discord.py installed. I also installed requests by doing pip install requests and it downloaded it fine. Whenever i run the code, i get this error. How can i fix this issue?

```
  File "c:\Users\colee\Desktop\Ultimate Bot\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

This is my import,

```
import requests
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to install the `requests` package. Try `python -m pip install requests`

Comment: @khuynh It says that the requirement is already satisficed.

Comment: Sounds like you have two different versions of python installed, and you installed it for the wrong version.  Show us the output of `pip --version`, and show us what python version you are using to run code.

Comment: @JohnGordon pip 21.1.1

Comment: `pip --version` also includes the python version.  Please show that.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry.. i didn't read the entire message. Python 3.9. Python 3.9.5 to be exact.

Comment: What version of Python are you using to run code?  If you're not sure, you can use this code to find out `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: @JohnGordon 3.9

Comment: @JohnGordon `Python version
3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
Version info.
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: Hmm. Show the output of this code also: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @JohnGordon `['c:\\Users\\colee\\Desktop\\Ultimate Bot', 'C:\\Users\\colee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\colee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\colee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\colee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39', 'C:\\Users\\colee\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']`

Comment: Is `requests` installed in any of those directories?  (`pip --version` should show you the actual directory where it would install packages.)

Comment: @JohnGordon How can i do that?

Comment: if you run code with command `python` then you can use `python -m pip install ...` to make sure you install module for correct python.

Comment: Run `pip show requests` and look for the `Location:` output.

Comment: Maybe you have to put it into the python interpreter. In PYCharm(What I use) you have to go to python interpreter click add, search for what your looking for and add it. then you should be good.